# Find overlapping in below data in plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

```
code  Low   High
A      0      99
E      0      99
T      0      99
A    100     **199**
E    100     **199**
T    100     **199**
A    **199**     299
E    **199**     299
T    **199**     299
A    300     399
E    300     399
T    300     399
```

I want to check the overlapping such as 199. If its overlap then throw the exception in oracle.

Comment: If you want to throw an exception you'll have to use PLSQL. Is the value 199 a given value, or do you need to find duplicates in the Low/High columns? ie: if you have a 0 in the High column does the program needs to throw the exception?

Comment: What do you want to do with that exception? Do you need to get those values or just inform about existence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a single query and then handle it via the `IF` condition.

Query to identify if an exception should be thrown:

```
SELECT MIN(CASE WHEN LAG_HIGH BETWEEN LOW AND HIGH THEN 'EXCEPTION'
                ELSE 'NO EXCEPTION'
           END) AS RESULT
  FROM (SELECT T.*,
               LAG(HIGH) OVER(PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY LOW) AS LAG_HIGH
          FROM YOUR_TABLE T);
```

If you want all the codes for which exception is raised, then you can use the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CODES FROM
(SELECT CASE WHEN LAG_HIGH BETWEEN LOW AND HIGH THEN CODE
               END AS CODES
      FROM (SELECT T.*,
                   LAG(HIGH) OVER(PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY LOW) AS LAG_HIGH
              FROM YOUR_TABLE T))
WHERE CODES IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Hi Tejash its working but Can you told me how I can find the code for which the overlapping arises?

Comment: Can I use same logic in trigger after insert?

Comment: In trigger? Please ask a new question with details so that We can help you with the proper scenario.

Answer (score 0):

A Procedure with a cursor containing a query with `LAG()` analytic function might be created

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Pr_Check_Overlap( i_code tab.code%type ) IS
BEGIN
    FOR c IN
    (
      SELECT t.*, LAG(high,1,high) OVER (PARTITION BY code ORDER BY code,low) AS previous_high
        FROM tab t
       WHERE code=i_code
       ORDER BY Low
     )
    LOOP
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(c.code||'   '||c.low||'   '||c.high);
      IF c.low = c.previous_high THEN
         RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20101, 'First Met Overlapping Value is '||c.low );
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

and called with interchangeably three values for its parameter like this

```
BEGIN
  Pr_Check_Overlap('A'); -- 'E', 'T'
END;
```